# ClientWebSocket make sure that message has been sent and connection is alive

Tags: c#, .net

Background: External factors force me to implement a simple websocket client in C# and I would like to keep the number of third party dependencies low. So it would be nice to stick with System.Net.WebSockets if possible.

Objective: Send a series of JSON objects as individual messages to a websocket server. Throw an exception if sending fails with any reasonable timeout. Throw an exception if the underlying TCP connection breaks between new objects becoming available.

Sending code:

```
// ws is an instance of System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket
ArraySegment<byte> json = new ArraySegment<byte> 
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)));

if (!ws.SendAsync(json, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, 
CancellationToken.None).Wait(10000))
{
    throw new Exception("Error: Websocket send timeout");
}
Console.Write("Sent")
```

My problem with this code is that when I see the client program printing "Sent", the server will not receive that message until several more invocations of SendAsync. My impression is that it is stuck in some kind of internal message buffer until the buffer spills over.

Similarly, breaking the underlying TCP connection does not result in the next SendAsync throwing an exception until several messages later.

Checking if websocket is alive without sending:
The keepalive is set to the default value 30s. Yet I have never seen ws.State return anything but WebSocketState.Open, even minutes after disconnecting the Server if I don't have any messages to send in between.

Am I fundamentally confused about how ClientWebSocket is supposed to be used, does it simply not work, or did I miss some detail in the documentation?

Comment: Are you supposed to be using raw sockets or websockets? If you are using websockets, then the .NET websocket takes care of timeouts, failures, and broken connections. Sounds like it might be an issue on the server side.

Comment: I am using websockets on the server as well. I don't think this is a server side issue, but I will need to verify once again that unplugging the network cable is not detected before excluding that option.

Answer (score 1):

You should `await` your async method in a `Task.Run`  :

```
Task.Run(() => {  
  if (!await ws.SendAsync(json, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, 
  CancellationToken.None))
  {
    throw new Exception("Error: Websocket send timeout");
  }
  Console.Write("Sent");
} ).Wait(10000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify a bit why await and Task.Run are necessary? 

I was under the impression that .Wait(10000) should block until the send is finished or out of time? What does await accomplish here?

Regarding Task.Run(): wouldn't that make this piece of code non-blocking again? Maybe I didn't make clear in my question that I want the code to block until the message was sent or sending failed.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to move the wait, now you will write "Sent" only if it's done, it's the whole purpose of this.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work. But I'm still confused about the difference between await and .Wait(). I thought await and .Wait(-1) would have same effect of making the statement blocking. What is wrong with my initial attempt.

Comment: It wont solve your problem, but you can do a workaround based on the fact the part near `console.write("sent")` is executed or not.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. I will try your code as soon as I can, but for the moment I don't understand why await should accomplish what .Wait() failed to do (block until the message is actually sent). I will have to understand that before accepting the answer.

If I understand your idea correctly I also think the `if` and `Console.Write("Sent")` should be moved outside the `Task.Run` block, otherwise the exception wont happen in case of timeout.